# Entity Framework não atualiza meu banco de dados

Tags: entity-framework-6

Estou utilizando `EF6`

E acontece que quando uso `Update-Database` ele não atualiza meu banco de dados.

Por exemplo

Eu tenho meu model:

```
public class Cliente 
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Se eu adicionar uma nova propriedade:

```
public string CNPJ {get;set;}
```

E rodar `Update-Database` ou `Update-Database -force`
Ele não atualiza, e ao acessar ele da erro e informa para fazer o migrations

O que eu já fiz foi:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration InitialCreate
```

No arquivo de `Configuration` setei o `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled`:

```
   public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Com `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` você não precisa gerar Migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas maneiras de resolver.

## 1. Reverta o banco para uma Migration que você sabe que funciona

Isto é o caso de projetos com geração manual de Migrations. Utilize o seguinte comando:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:NomeDaMigrationSemOPontoCsNoFinal
```

## 2. Apague o banco de desenvolvimento

Sem dó. Se for SQL Server, pelo Management Studio, entre na base de dados e exclua o database inteiro (botão direito > Excluir ou Delete). Experimente executar o `Update-Database` de novo.

Se achar necessário, faça um backup do banco, mas normalmente não é.